# Eclipse (oxygen) : What is the meaning of the 3 sections of the preview window (Colors and Fonts)?

Tags: eclipse, fonts, colors, preview

In Eclipse(oxygen 4.7) General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts there is a "preview" section containing 3 different versions of the color attribute selected.  Can someone explain what each version is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Preview*** shows the chosen color:

- Left: as **text color on a grey background** (e. g. for the use as font color in dialogs)
- Middle: as **background color** with a black (`Sample text`) and a white text (`RGB(...)`) on it
- Right: as **text color on a white background** (e. g. for the use as font color in a text editor)

It is a generic color preview: for font colors ignore the middle preview; for non-font colors ignore the left and right preview.

Example for *Active hyperlink text color*:

[image]